# Alternatives to Matlab's Image Processing Toolkit

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Are there any comprehensive open-source alternatives to Matlab's Image Processing Toolkit?

Comment: There is many free image processing libraries in python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94875/image-processing-in-python

Answer (score 8):

Octave's [image](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/index.html)
And for Scilab there is [SIP](http://siptoolbox.sourceforge.net/) and [SIVP](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/)

Both Octave and Scilab are *very* Matlab like, but I'm not sure how similar the image toolkits are.

Also look into [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) if you are comfortable with C/C++ or Python

Answer (score 4):

I assume the reason you want an open source option is to have a free option or some other open-source license related reason.

However, if it's just so you can actually see the source to understand how algorithms are implemented in a particular package (something I often am curious about), bear in mind you can see the source for MATLAB functions by entering edit followed by the function name in the command window. E.g., if I wanted to know how the MATLAB implementation of the function label2rgb works, you can type "edit label2rgb" into the command window and it will open that m file.

Furthermore, if you find you just wish you could modify the behaviour of certain functions slightly, you can always get their source as I described, then modify. However, make sure to always save the results in a seperate m-file, ideally with a different name and in a different location so you don't end up breaking a MATLAB function and having to reinstall to get it back.

In Windows 7 at least, the folder "C:\Users\%your_username%\Documents\MATLAB" is included in the MATLAB search path for functions, so if you wanted to tweak label2rgb, you might copy it into that folder, rename it label2rgb_custom.m, and make your mods. You could then run it from anywhere in MATLAB by calling label2rgb_custom().

Comment: Not all Matlab functions will reveal the actual code through `edit`. If they are proprietary, you'll just see the comments related to `help` but nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Try [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html) (also read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageJ)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above:Octave and ImageJ

If you do have Matlab there is an open source Image Processing toolbox:
http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/456

For raster check Gimp: http://www.gimp.org/
And Inagemagik http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative to MATLAB is OpenCV.
In fact it is better than MATLAB for real time video and image processing applications.
There are lots of resources available online to support it and all u need is basic C programming skills.

Best book is Learning computer vision using OpenCV by gray bradski whose e-book u can easily find.

I have compiled a list of tutorials for beginners on my blog
http://8a52labs.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

use AForget.net if you use C#. AForge.net is supported Image Processing and AI

Answer (score 0):

From my experience [SciLab](https://www.scilab.org/download/5.4.1) is the best alternative for matlab,it has built in conversion support from matlab to scilab and scilab to matlab. It is open source, so you can also contribute its development and use it for free.