# Running matlab script without having the required toolbox

Tags: matlab

I have downloaded a matlab code for dithering the images but I don't have the Image Processing toolbox and I don't want to buy it for running this code. Is there any way for running the script?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which functions form the toolbox does your script need? You might be able to find free Octave equivalents or free equivalents from the file exchange

Comment: It needs a lot of functions more than 20 functions so that means  I need the whole toolbox Or another software than can run matlab scripts

Comment: Octave is your best bet then. Or try finding a free matlab image processing toolbox online and try reproduce your script to use the free tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319355/alternatives-to-matlabs-image-processing-toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Octave, or Scilab, or OpenCV, or there are many other open source, and free, alternatives.

But while you're investigating and trying those out, just make sure to measure how much time you're spending on it. If your script uses more than 20 functions from Image processing Toolbox (as you indicated in a comment) then it may be a lot of effort, and depending on how much your time is worth per hour, you may well find it would be better to just buy the toolbox. That's of course just my advice - your choice.

If you're at a university, you will likely be able to get a cheaper educational pricing, or be able to buy the Student edition of MATLAB that includes Image Processing Toolbox. It's also possible to purchase a time-limited license of MATLAB (six months or a year) for a discount, although that pricing is very unadvertised by MathWorks, and you would need to call and speak to a MathWorks account manager to request it.

Comment: Also you can get a 30-day free trial to decide if it's worth it or not

Answer (score -1):

You can download [Scilab](https://www.scilab.org/download/5.4.1) , it is a similar platform like Matlab, but it is open source,You dont have to spend your money, You can run matlab code using scilab.

Comment: It could't read the script and it didn't recognize the functions like imread, imshow or the others

Comment: well, you have to convert the script using its built in fucntion matlab to scilab. You can find it in app section.