# CImg Python 3 bindings or something at least comparable?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-3.x, cimg

i'm searching a Python lib with good image processing functionalities .
I was searching for CImg (which i've already used on C++ projects) bindings, but i wasn't lucky.
I found PIL, but it lacks a lot of features that CImg has so, is there any good alternative ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

PIL is good, but i need Python 3 support on a Mac OS X system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to enumerate the functionality that you find desirable which is there in Cimg and not in PIL.

Discussion on SO

- [Image Processing, In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94875/image-processing-in-python)

pypi also throws up a lot of modules on image processing. Try seeing, if some of them is suitable for you.

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=image+processing&submit=search

Comment: PIL is good, but i need Python 3 support on a Mac OS X system.