# Digital image correlation libraries for a mac

Tags: python, macos, image-processing

I'm working on a project to develop a [Digital Image Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_correlation) tool for measuring surface strains. Does anyone know of any Mac compatible libraries that I can use to do the DIC processing. I was thinking that this might be something where there is a Python library but I have not yet managed to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread [Image Processing, In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94875/image-processing-in-python)

Then there is the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) with [Python interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface)

Don't know about the MAC-part though...